# Strange labels with suffix -0, -1 in jmeter results

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

We recently updated apache jmeter from v4.0 to the latest v5.4.3.

The tests are running fine, but we have strange results.
The requests appear with 3 different labels (without suffix or -0 / -1 appended).

```
timeStamp,     label,      responseCode, threadName
1643834640785, API call,   200,          Load Group 1 1-1
1643834640785, API call-0, 302,          Load Group 1 1-1
1643834641189, API call-1, 200,          Load Group 1 1-1
1643834640785, API call,   200,          Load Group 1 1-2
....
```

It seems to me this happens, when the same thread calls the API multiple times.

I am not a jmeter and I am not sure why this happens and how to fix it. Also I don't know what information is needed to analyze the problem correctly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm seeing [HTTP Status 302](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) which means [redirection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) (for example from HTTP to HTTPS or from global website to country-specific website), in that case JMeter generates additional Sub-Result.

The "strange" labels is how JMeter calculates throughput for [embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses) and the cumulative execution time of the parent sampler in case of redirects as well.

[image]

The question is what do you want to do with this.

The options are in:

1. Take it for granted given the above explanation
2. If you want the "strange" labels to be resolved into real URLs - tick "Functional Testing" box in the [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)

   [image]

   or add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   subresults.disable_renaming=true
   ```
3. If you want to get rid of these subresults completely - add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false
   ```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [JMeter Properties Reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)

Comment: Thank you so much, this perfectly explains the reason and the solution(s). I went with `jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false` and it works as I need it.